# In CakePHP 1.3 is there any advantage of using $this->Controller->Session over $this->Session in a component?

Tags: session, cakephp, persistence, components

I'm using a modified version of Felix Geisendörfer's SimpleAuth/SimpleAcl components that I've combined into a single Component, Simple_Authable.

I changed his startup() function to initialize() to not clutter the beforeFilter function in my app_controller.

One of the things that this component does is check who the active user is and if that user can't be found it either looks him up based on the primary User.id or uses 'guest'. Either way, the component uses $this->Controller->Session->write() to save the active user or guest information.

I'm also using Felix's Authsome plugin instead of the default CakePHP Auth component.

When I'm logging in, the active user is guest, obviously.

After I've submitted the form, the active user is still guest because the component's initialize() function is firing before everything else. Then, the Authsome plugin comes into play and validates my user as "root" and also calls $this->SimpleAuthable->setActiveUser($id, true); to force SimpleAuthable to update the active user information it is storing via $this->Controller->Session; Then I am redirected and my simple Session information and DebugKit's Session tab reflect that I am indeed the root user.

However, when I try to navigate to an 'admin' page, let's say /admin/users/index, lo and behold SimpleAuthable thinks I'm still a 'guest' user because when it performs a $this->Controller->Session->read() call to the key holding my user id, it is getting an empty response, i.e., the data stored on the previous page didn't persist.

Maybe there is something funky happening between Authsome & SimpleAuthable, but things look pretty straightforward and to my mind, $this->Controller->Session *should* be saving and persisting the data written to it.

So, I'm looking at refactoring all the calls to $this->Controller->Session and replacing them with $this->Session but first I wanted to throw this out to the community and see if anybody has seen anything similar and if so how did they resolve it.

Sincerely,
  Christopher.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem... I'm also using Joshua McNeese's Permissionable plugin and I needed to disable it for the $this->Controller->{$this->userModel}->findById($id); in my SimpleAuthable component when I try to lookup the current active user.

Note to self: I would have caught this faster if I had some unit testing in place :(.